# Finding the dependency of X and Y values

Tags: probability, expectation

I have joint probability of two variables X and Y,

\begin{array}[]
\hline
     & y=-1  & y=0  & y=1   & y=2  &P(X=x_i) \\
x=0 & 0.06  & 0.25 & 0.02  & 0.02  & 0.35\\
x=1 & 0.31  & 0.02 & 0.27  & 0.02  & 0.62\\
x=2 & 0.018 & 0    & 0.006 & 0.006 & 0.03\\
P(Y=y_i) & 0.388 & 0.27 & 0.296 & 0.046 & 1
\end{array}

I calculated their marginal dependencies and added it to the above last row and column respectively.

I calculated the expectation value using the formula,

$E(X)=\sum_{i=0}^{2}(X_{i}*P(X_{i}))$

and calculated $E(X)=0.68$ and $E(Y)=0$, while calculating $E(XY)$, I need to chose the formula based upon the dependency of X and Y.

**How can i deduce the dependency?.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The random variables are not independent. Probably the simplest way to do this is to note that $\Pr(X=2\cap Y=0)=0$, while neither $\Pr(X=2)$ nor $\Pr(Y=0)$ is $0$. The random variables would be independent if and only if for *every* $x$ and $y$, $\Pr(X=y\cap Y=y)=\Pr(X=x)\Pr(Y=y)$.

But you may want to find out whether the random variables are *correlated* or not. (If they are independent, they are uncorrelated, but it is possible for random variables to be uncorrelated but not independent.)

The random variables are uncorrelated precisely if $E(XY)=E(X)E(Y)$. So you need to compute $E(XY)$. I will assume you know how to do that. Please leave a message if that poses difficulty.

If they are correlated, you may wish to compute the *correlation coefficient*. This is $\frac{E(XY)-E(X)E(Y)}{\sqrt{\text{Var}(X)\text{Var(Y)}}}$. Additional calculation will be needed to find the variances.

Comment: I know ff-topic comments are not welcome in general, but as I read your answer: "Please leave a message if that poses difficulty." I could not help but admire your intentions not only to provide help but your willingness to even offer more help!

Comment: @NoChance: OP did a significant amount of work.

Comment: I found that E(XY)=Sum of (XYP(X)P(Y), but isn't it actually equivalent to E(X).E(Y)?. So my E(XY) would be 0, since E(Y)=0. Am I correct in my observation?.

Comment: $E(XY)$ is $\sum_{x,y} \Pr(X=x\cap Y=y)$. In this particular table, as I pointed out, it is in general not the case that $\Pr(X=x\cap Y=y)=\Pr(X=x)\Pr(Y=y)$. So you need to compute $\sum_{x,y} \Pr(X=x\cap Y=y)$. **If** this turns out to be $0$, then because $E(Y)=0$, the random variables are uncorrelated. **Added:** I did the calculation (it is not hard since there are lots of zeros) and found that $\sum_{x,y} \Pr(X=x\cap Y=y)$.is indeed $0$, so $X$ and $Y$ are uncorrelated. But as I pointed out, they are not independent.

Comment: I want to stress again that the calculation of $E(XY)$, as you describe it, is not right. However, it so happens that the wrong calculation gives the right value for $E(XY)$. This will seldom happen.

Comment: A big fat giant thank you :)

Comment: You are welcome. I take it that you saw that the "negative" contribution the expectation was $(-1)(0.27)+(-2)(0.018)$. The positive contribution is $(1)(0.27)$ plus other terms I won't write down. It all adds up to $0$.

Comment: $\begin{align}\mathsf E(XY) ~=~& \sum\limits_{~x=0~}^2\sum\limits_{~y=-1~}^2 xy~\mathsf P(X=x,Y=y)
\\ ~=~& (-0.31+0.27+2\cdot0.02)+2(-0.018+0.006+2\cdot 0.006)
\\ ~=~& 0
\end{align}$